# full width web page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying a web page with 3 section together:

1. div A width:200px
2. div B full width
3. div C width:10px;

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main{
    min-width: 1200px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#F00;
}

.a{
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#0F0;
    float:left;
}

.b{
    height:500px;
    background-color:#00F;
    float:left;
}

.c{
    width:10px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#FF0;
    float:left;
}
```

But the div B not full screen!How to correct this?

Comment: Add this .b{
    height:500px;
    background-color:#00F;
    width:100%;
}

Comment: It's **really** unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css_liquid_layout_31_fixed_fluid_fixed/

Comment: Div A and C with fixed width and Div B with variant width. A left, B center and C right and web page full screen.

Comment: Yes but with CSS , no script

Comment: @FatemehNamkhah look into using bootstrap (it's built by the people who made Twitter). It allows you to add columns, rows,etc to your page that adjust dynamically and look fitting. I know it's not a direct help but it is definitely worth considering.

Comment: Find a detailed explanantion of the necessary steps to solve this in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reorder your `<div>`. First `<div class="a">`, then `<div class="c">`, then `<div class="b">`:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="a">A</div>
    <div class="c">C</div>
    <div class="b">B</div>
</div>
```

As a next step, you will have to remove the `float: left;` from `.b` (making elements float removes the typical block level element behaviour of grabbing the available width) and change the float for `.c` to right.

The last step then will have to be that you will have to assign the width you want for all 3 to their container `.main`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.b
{
 background-color:#00F;
 float:left;
 height:500px;
 min-width: 990px; /* 1200 -200-10*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need some css lib like bootstrap etc or use media queries.

For fix wide the css will look like

```
.main{
    min-width: 1200px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:green;
}

.a{
    width:200px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#0F0;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

.b{
    height:500px;
    background-color:#0F0;
    display:inline-block;
    width:990px;
}

.c{
    width:10px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#FF0;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
}
```